# Imagemagick flips direction of LinearGradient

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png

I've implemented a go script that generates a custom playing card based on a json input file. The output is svg. In order to print the card, I need to convert it to png. Therefore I installed ImageMagick.

I'm using the convert command line tool:

```
convert output.svg output.png
```

This is the svg markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated by SVGo -->
<svg width="630" height="891"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="h" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1.00"/>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(255,255,255)" stop-opacity="1.00"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="630" height="891" style="fill:black"/>
<rect x="10" y="10" width="610" height="871" style="fill:url(#h)"/>
<text x="20" y="89" style="fill:black;font-size:30pt;text-anchor:start">1 Sold</text>
<text x="610" y="89" style="fill:black;font-size:30pt;text-anchor:end">Gegenstand</text>
<line x1="20" y1="98" x2="610" y2="98" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
<text x="20" y="151" style="font-family:monospace;fill:black;font-size:25pt;text-anchor:start">Bogen</text>
<text x="20" y="534" style="fill:black;font-size:20pt;text-anchor:start">Wird in einer Schmiede hergestellt</text>
<text x="20" y="579" style="fill:black;font-size:20pt;text-anchor:start"></text>
<text x="20" y="623" style="fill:black;font-size:15pt;text-anchor:start">Vor dem Kampf hat der Bogenschütze eine Wahrscheinlichkeit</text>
<text x="20" y="641" style="fill:black;font-size:15pt;text-anchor:start">von 4,5,6 dass der dem Gegner einen Lebenspunkt abzieht</text>
</svg>
```

If you paste this in an svg file and open it in your browser, you can see that the background is a rect with a lineargradient. The bottom of the card is red and towards the top it slowly turns to white. After converting the file to png, it looks like this:

[image]

The language on the card is German, but the text is not important. It is rendered correctly. The problem is the inverted gradient. At first I designed the cards with Gimp but then I decided to automate the process. Unfortunately I already printed a lot of these cards and would like to keep the layout consistent.

I'm rather sure that the flipped gradient is not my fault. Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer display the same image. Maybe my usage of ImageMagick is wrong ?

Could you recommend an alternative tool ?

Comment: I changed the colors and the direction of the gradient. This "double negation" didn't affect the svg layout, but now ImageMagick converts the images correctly. You might want to make your comment an answer. Ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the linarGradient to have y1="0%" and y2="100%" then swap the offsets of the stop colours you can work around that bug in ImageMagick.